# which is better to use ( a not in b) or (not a in b ) in python?

Tags: python

I am an intermediate in python programming but I faced this in python condition,

`a not in b`
and
`not a in b`

for example

```
item_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
if 6 not in  item_list:
    print('6 not found')

elif not 9 in item_list:
    print('9 not found')
```

The all codes above give me the same results is there any difference from view of performance or bugs.

Comment: `not in` definitely does what you want. I'm not sure if `is not in` is semantically identical or not, it might trip you up in some edge cases (I'm really not sure).

Comment: Have you benchmarked each method to see which is faster? Why take our word for it?

Comment: `is not in` is a syntax error.

Comment: `if 6 is not in item_list:` is a syntax error. It cannot give the same result as the variant without `is`.

Comment: Did you mistakenly test `if 6 is not item_list`? Because that would be `True` for different reasons: `6` is not the same object as the list `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: I don't quite get the point of the revised question. Just because the two operations give the same result *in this specific case* does not make them equivalent. An integer will *always* be unequal to a list; an integer *may-or-may-not* be in a list. Without giving more details why you think these should be equivalent, you might as well ask why not to prefer ``if False:`` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is not in` isn't valid Python syntax. Contrary to your claims, it doesn't work.

`not in` is the right way of doing it.